# Factorial using VBScript Function

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript

I am New to VBscript,
I want to find out factorial of a given number. I am using this code. This will display the button But while tap on the button nothing will happen. Please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/vbscript">
        sub fact

        n=cint(inputbox("Enter a number"))
        dim f
        f=1
        if n<0 then
        msgbox "Invalid number"
        elseif n=0 or n=1 then
        msgbox "The factorial of given number "&n&" is :"&f
        else
        for i=n to 2 step -1
        f=f*i
        next
        msgbox "The factorial of given number "&n&" is :"&f
        end if
        end sub

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick= "fact()" value="Factorial">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser are you using? Only IE can run VBS code

Your code works for me in IE (you'll get a prompt about allowing scripts on the page, which you have to accept)

Comment: Then you can't use VBScript: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/default.asp)

Comment: @SHIDHIN.T.S For client-side code VBScript is a poor choice in most cases, unless you're absolutely sure that every client will be running IE. JavaScript would be preferable, because it's supported by far more browsers and platforms.